# Groovy iterating through Map of Maps

Tags: dictionary, groovy

Let's say I have a Map:

```
Map exampleMap = ["person1": ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "id": "1"], "person2": ["firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "id": "2"]]
```

I want to iterate through this Map and print out the key and the values.

For example:

```
exampleMap.each{ item, key ->
    println item[key]
    println item["firstName"]
    println item["lastName"]
```

}

The sample output I want:

```
person1
John
Doe
```

The above approach gives me an error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: firstName for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
```

I tried:

```
Map exampleMap = ["person1": ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "id": "1"], "person2": ["firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "id": "2"]] as ConfigObject
def props = exampleMap.toProperties()
```

But it would output `key` as a `person1.firstName`. Is it possible to output just `person1`?

Or what would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the closure parameter order:

```
Map exampleMap = ["person1": ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "id": "1"], "person2": ["firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "id": "2"]]

exampleMap.each{ key, item ->
    println key
    println item["firstName"]
    println item["lastName"]
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJzzTSxQSK1IzC3ISfUFMm0VopUKUouK8_MMlayA7LTMouISv8TcVCBPySs_I09JR0EpJxEh5pKfChLKTAFxDJVigWyIfiMs-hPzUvHqN1KKjeXiQjhHLzUxOaNaITu1UkchsyQ1V0HXjksBCAqKMvNKcvJAEih8kBpkO2OxyMItj-Wq5eICK4ABAKLwT3U).